# Насекомое и сомнение

Tags: морфология, склонение, существительные

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему существительные *насекомое* и *сомнение* не относятся к одному склонению. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: http://studopedia.org/6-34698.html  // http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37382.php

Comment: Здесь не принято давать ответы в виде ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

> Объясните, пожалуйста, почему существительные насекомое и сомнение не относятся к одному склонению. Заранее большое спасибо.

Потому что к одному склонению относятся существительные, которые ***склоняются*** одинаково, с одинаковыми окончаниями (с точностью до орфографических и фонетических тонкостей обусловленных, например, твердостью-мягкостью основы).

А наши существительные склоняются по-разному:

Р. Чего? насеком**ого**, сомнени**я**
Д. Чему? насеком**ому**, сомнени**ю**

и т.д.

Насекомое склоняется как прилагательное ("адъенктивное" склонение), а сомнение - как обычное существительного среднего рода (на ие).

Это и есть **разные** склонения.

Answer (score 0):

Насеко́мое - калька из франц. insecte (то же) от лат. insectum, первонач. "насеченное, с насечками (животное).

Таким образом, "насекомое" (насеченное) склоняется по образцу прилагательного, а не существительного, как "сомнение".